# Pass extra variable to callback function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling, callback

I am trying to create a simple method that logs out my DB operation results in a prettified format in the console. I want to pass an extra variable (`operationName`) to my custom logger callback function when my DB finishes an operation.

```js
// Custom logger (simplified)
const dbLogger = (error, data, operationName) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`${operationName} failed`, error)
  }
  console.log(`${operationName} success`, data)
}

// mongodb operations
import ChatModel from 'somewhere';

function createMessage() {
  const newChatAdded = new ChatModel({
    message: 'Hi'
  })
  ChatModel.save(newChatAdded, dbLogger);
}
```

Here the **error** and **data** in our callback is provided by the `ChatModel.save` method but I want to send a 3rd parameter **operationName** (eg. 'save' or 'delete') as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways, take your pick!

1. use anonymous function with a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) these on calling `dbLogger`:

   ```
   ChatModel.save(newChatAdded, (...args) => dbLogger(...args, "save");
   ```
2. use a [bound function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

   Change your `dbLogger` function signature to accept `operationName` as the first argument:

   ```
   const dbLogger = (operationName, error, data) => {
     if (error) {
       console.log(`${operationName} failed`, error)
     }
     console.log(`${operationName} success`, data)
   }
   ```

   Create new bound log function which will always be called with "save" as the first argument.

   ```
   ChatModel.save(newChatAdded, dbLogger.bind(null, "save");
   ```

   This is also called ["partial application"](https://javascript.info/currying-partials).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. Just a question. So in this case dbLogger.bind creates a new function with the string "save" as the first parameter right? How are the "data" and "error" argument passed during this process?

Comment: That is equivalent - you are just assigning reference to the bound function to a variable first. You can read about `Function.prototype.bind` in the link to MDN in my answer, that should make it clearer what is happening; essentially we are creating a _new_ function with a "fixed" first argument, but where that first argument is not expected in calls to the function. So as far as the caller is concerned the function has the signature `(error, data)`.

Comment: Ah I see that it returns a copy of the given function with a specified this and initial arguments set. Got it! Thanks  again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ChatModel.save(newChatAdded, (error, data) => dbLogger(error, data, 'save'));
```

If you'd change the order of your parameters, you could make that more succinct:

```
const dbLogger = (operationName, error, data) => ...

ChatModel.save(newChatAdded, dbLogger.bind(null, 'save'));
```